# Customize jquerymobile button

Tags: css, jquery-mobile

Can anyone help me on how to remove the white line around the jquery mobile button 
, i have added background image to it and want to remove that line.

Comment: which button. Show us the example

Comment: Please provide us with an example and some code so we can even begin to try to help you.

Comment: Yes sure, Here is the FIDDLE http://jsfiddle.net/fepT4/

Comment: Fixed (see the css in my answer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/fepT4/2/

Like others said, it is hard to help you out if you don't have an example code or screenshot to show us what you want to achieve. In general, to remove the border, use css `border-style: none;` If this is not what you want, please provide more info.

Comment: Thanks @IsabelHM, it helped. Yes missed to add the code actually, Thanks a lot

Comment: Glad to help! If you can, please select it as the answer to conclude the question. Thnx